# can you use call or apply with new?

Tags: javascript, resig

related to [How can I call a javascript constructor using call or apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362471/how-can-i-call-a-javascript-constructor-using-call-or-apply)

but not the same, I'm trying to apply the SO answers to [John Resig's forcing a constructor](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#36) when not called properly.

```
function User(first, last){ 
  if ( !(this instanceof User) )
    // the line I want to replace, or remove the redundancy from:
    return new User(first, last);

  this.name = first + " " + last; 
} 

var name = "Resig"; 
var user = User("John", name); 

assert( user, "This was defined correctly, even if it was by mistake." ); 
assert( name == "Resig", "The right name was maintained." );
```

The target line of code means every time the constructor changes, someone has to remember to change the internal self-call arguments. I've already had a project trip over this issue 3 times in the last 3 days.

All the examples in the linked question talk about passing the `constructor`, but what is the `constructor` in this case? It's not even finished being defined yet.

but so far all attempts do not pass the test, or throw a stackoverflow.

How do I make sure the constructor being called results in something that responds properly to `instanceof User` even when called without the `new` keyword, while eliminating the repetition of argument parameters?

Comment: I'm not seeing why the question you linked (or rather, its answers) aren't applicable to your scenario...?

Comment: I've edited your code (slightly, as the edit comment notes); feel free to roll back if you'd rather.

Comment: This just hurts my eyes. Why do this at all? Simply ask the programmer to use `new`. That is what it was made for.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  perhaps I'm reading out of my league discussions, I could not see how to apply them this way.

Comment: @Pinoniq it's not necessarily a good practice, but I did want to understand how I could apply the concepts together.

Comment: @DavidThomas good edit, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options for you, all using `Object.create`:

#### Option 1:

```
function User(first, last){ 
  var rv;

  if ( !(this instanceof User) ) {
    // They called us without `new`: Create an object backed by `User.prototype`:
    rv = Object.create(User.prototype);

    // Now, call this function applying the arguments
    User.apply(rv, arguments);

    // Return the object
    return rv;
  }

  // Normal constructor stuff    
  this.name = first + " " + last; 
}
```

Of course, all of that logic doesn't have to be repeated for every constructor function you create, you can use a helper function:

```
function constructWith(obj, ctor, args) {
    if (obj instanceof ctor) {
        return null;
    }
    obj = Object.create(ctor.prototype);
    ctor.apply(obj, args);
    return obj;
}
```

then

```
function User(first, last){ 
  var rv;

  if ((rv = constructWith(this, User, arguments)) != null) {
      return rv;
  }

  // Normal constructor stuff    
  this.name = first + " " + last; 
}
```

#### Option 2: Don't use `this` much:

```
function User(first, last){ 
  var rv;

  if (this instanceof User) {
    // They (probably) used `new`, all is good, use `this`
    rv = this;
  } else {
    // They didn't use `new`, create an object backed by `User.prototype`
    rv = Object.create(User.prototype);
  }

  // ...use `rv`, not `this`, from here on

  rv.name = first + " " + last; 

  // This is important for the case where they didn't use `new`, and harmless
  // in the case where they did.
  return rv;
}
```

As you can see, this is a lot simpler, but if you really like your syntax highlighting (seriously, I have a client to whom it really matters that `this` jumps out), etc...

And of course, you can wrap that up in a helper:

```
function useOrConstruct(obj, ctor) {
    return obj instanceof ctor ? obj : Object.create(ctor.prototype);
}
```

Then

```
function User(first, last){ 
  var rv = useOrConstruct(this, User);

  // ...use `rv`, not `this`, from here on

  rv.name = first + " " + last; 

  // This is important for the case where they didn't use `new`, and harmless
  // in the case where they did.
  return rv;
}
```

#### Option 3: `constructOMatic`

Of course, if we're going to define helpers, maybe we should go whole-hog:

```
function User() {
    return constructOMatic(this, User, arguments, function(first, last) {
        this.name = first + " " + last;
    });
}
```

...where `constructOMatic` is:

```
function constructOMatic(obj, ctor, args, callback) {
    var rv;
    if (!(obj instanceof ctor)) {
        obj = Object.create(ctor.prototype);
    }
    rv = callback.apply(obj, args);
    return rv !== null && typeof rv === "object" ? rv : obj;
}
```

Now, you can use `this` to your heart's content within the callback. That fiddling with `rv` vs. `obj` in the `return` at the end is to emulate the behavior of `new` (the result of a `new` expression is the object created by the `new` operator *unless* the constructor function returns a non-`null` object reference, in which case that takes precedence).

---

`Object.create` is an ES5 feature found on all modern browsers, but the single-argument version of it used above can be shimmed for out-of-date browsers:

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function(proto, props) {
        if (typeof props !== "undefined") {
            throw "The two-argument version of Object.create cannot be shimmed.";
        }
        function ctor() { }
        ctor.prototype = proto;
        return new ctor; // Yes, you really don't need () (but put them on if you prefer)
    };
}
```

Comment: your solution works, thanks. I can accept in 6 minutes

Comment: @Maslow: Glad that helped. I've added some notes to avoid repeating yourself.

Comment: in option 1, why is `rv` declared outside of the `if`? just to make it clearer that it would be in scope if the `if` is skipped? it isn't accessed outside of the `if`.

Comment: @Maslow: I always declare variables at the tops of functions, since that's where the declaration really is [thanks to hoisting](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html). (I think you already know what's in that linked article, but if not...)

Comment: yeah I'm familiar with it, tried to imply that in my comment

Comment: @Maslow: And you succeeded, it was a "just in case" link. :-) I've added a third option as well, which is naughty of me, I should be working...

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste are very easy and the code is clean. You need not to change it.

If you accept **`eval`**, you can do it like this:

```
function User(first, last){ 
  if ( !(this instanceof arguments.callee) ) {
    var name = arguments.callee.name;
    var param = [].map.call(arguments,function(e,i){return 'arguments['+i+']';});
    return eval('new '+name+'('+ param +')');
  }

  this.name = first + " " + last;
}

//test
var user1 = User("John", "Resig");
var user2 = new User("John", "Resig");
```

---

Without **`eval`**, you can do it like this:

```
function instantiate(C,a){
    switch(a.length){
        case 0: return new C();
        case 1: return new C(a[0]);
        case 2: return new C(a[0],a[1]);
        case 3: return new C(a[0],a[1],a[2]);
        case 4: return new C(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
        default : throw("too many arguments");
    }
}

function User(first, last){ 
  if ( !(this instanceof arguments.callee) ) {
    return instantiate(arguments.callee, arguments);
  }

  this.name = first + " " + last;
}


//test
var user1 = User("John", "Resig");
var user2 = new User("John", "Resig");
```

In ECMAScript 6, you can use the spread operator to apply a constructor with the new keyword to an array of arguments:

```
"use strict";
function User(first, last){ 
  if ( !(this instanceof User) ) {
    return new User(...arguments);
  }

  this.name = first + " " + last;
}
```